# Cannot replace a packed image in the uv image editor

Tags: uv, image

I was trying to replace an image in my UV image editor, but the image defaults to a different image. how do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to open the image again

Comment: You need to switch to edit mode first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your image is packed, replacing it is not possible (in newer blender this option is now grayed out in this case). You have to unpack it first, if you want to replace it.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: [Official manual](http://www.blender.org/manual/data_syste/introduction.html#pack-and-unpack-data) (though it could use some updates…). To unpack an individual file, just click on its 'packed' icon (between the `F` and `X` buttons, to the right of its name field).

Comment: @mont29 there is a typo in that link, (or there was in the docs when you posted!) the correct URL is https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/introduction.html#pack-and-unpack-data

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so to fix that you need to unpack the image.
To unpack the image,  next to the image tab (the one when you click on it it has the greyed out replace image)
there's skin.png right? Next to that there's a 3, an F, a +, and this wierd thing i can't describe.
Click on that weird thing i can't describe (lol)  and click "Use file from current directory (create when necessary)
BOOM! You can now click on replace image

Comment: If you can't describe something try to add screenshots with marked elements.