# Blender won't let me replace an image

Tags: image

I need help with blender. I got a minecraft intro template, and there is a skin on it I want to change. The only way to change it like how everyone does is go to the replace image on the picture file. But it isn't an option. For example, when I click on that image icon where you can select Save as image, Copy image, New image, and all that stuff, it's not an option. I mean it's still there but grayed out. Can anyone help me please?
[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the UV/Image editor?

Comment: Is the image [*packed*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38171/599)?